# Linux Mint 19.2 cinnamon desktop becomes very sluggish if left logged in for 24hrs

Tags: linux-mint, x11, cinnamon, lightdm

Running Linux mint 19.2 with all the latest updates and the video drivers from NVIDIA installed.

Upon logging in, the desktop is very snappy, even with multiple windows open.  Switching windows is fast, scrolling is fast, typing is fast.

If I let this desktop sit logged in until the next day, it is unusably slow.  Alt-tab takes 2-3 seconds to pop up the windows list, typing is slow.

Logging out and logging back in fixes it.

I've checked ssd space, CPU and memory with `htop` (64gb, plenty left), etc and I don't see any glaring culprits.

update:  today after the machine has been running over the weekend with me logged in, I notice  `cinnamon --replace` is using 60-70% cpu

Comment: Run something like `top` or `glances` when you first start up the system, then check to see if any processes are spiking in CPU usage after leaving the system on overnight..

Comment: I did that.   Nothing shows up.   Load and mem are low.

Comment: What version are your Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @ajgringo619 - 430.50.  The latest from nvidia's website

Comment: so you installed them via the .run file, instead of the PPA?

Comment: Same happens to me, but with integrated Intel Graphics. Curiously, another PC with same Mint version but with a NVidia video card works just fine...

Comment: Maybe there is something in `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: Anyone encountering the same problem:  I reinstalled the manually installed NVDIA drivers with the PPA drivers and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Not a definitive answer but it could be an extension causing problems. A quicker workaround to logging in/out would be to just issue a `cinnamon --replace`. Hopefully that won't disrupt your working state as much.